# too few arguments to function C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

// function prototypes
void intOutput();
void floatingPointOutput();
void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width);
void writeHeaderLine(int width);
void writeMathLine(int a, int b, int width);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "\nProject 1: Math and Functions";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nProject 1 Start.";
cout << "\nZack Cunningham";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nInteger Output Demo:";
cout << "\n";

intOutput();
floatingPointOutput();
intMathOperations();
writeHeaderLine();
writeMathLine();

cout << "\n";
cout << "\nProject 1 End.";
cout << "\n";

const int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
intMathOperations(12, 5, FIELD_WIDTH);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width){
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nInteger Math Operations Demo:";
cout << "\n";
writeHeaderLine(width);
cout << "\n";
for (int a = 0; a < rows; ++a){writeMathLine(a, b, width);
}
}


void writeHeaderLine(int width){
cout << "\n";
cout << setw(width) << "a";
cout << setw(width) << "b";
cout << setw(width) << "a * b";
cout << setw(width) << "a / b";
cout << setw(width)<< "a % b";
}

void writeMathLine(int width){
int a;
cout << setw(width) << a;
int b;
int rows;
for (int a = 0; a < rows; ++a){writeMathLine(a, b, width);
}
}

void floatingPointOutput(){
double a = 2000;
double b = 3;
double c = a / b;
cout << "\n" << a << " / " << b << " = ";
cout << "\n" << c;

cout << setprecision(10);
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << scientific; // scientific notation
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << fixed; // standard decimal notation
cout << "\n" << setw(20)<< c;
cout << left; // left justify
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << right;

// right justify (default)
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << setprecision(6); // return to default
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << "\n";
}

// function calls
void intOutput(){
cout << "\nInteger Output Demo:";
cout << "\n";
int a = 12;
int b = 12345678;
cout << "\n....5...10...15...20"; // spacing info
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << b;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(4) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(4) << b;
cout << left; // left justified
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << b;
cout << right; // right (default) justified
cout << "\n";
}
```

This is my code of course, it gives me 3 errors saying there is too few arguments with my last 3 functions. Any help would be appreciate it! To me it looks like all the arguments are valid, but I'm just a beginner any way.

Comment: When you post code here, tabs don't work well. So make sure you use a consistent number of spaces for each indent. It really helps readability. *Also*, `writeMathLine` declaration and implementation signatures differ. Pretty simple.

Comment: What arguments? You didn't provide any.

Comment: You are not passing any parameters to these functions?!?

Comment: Also, does Zack's teacher know that someone else is doing (read: trying to do) his homework for him?

Comment: *there is too few arguments* I think the error message speaks for itself

Comment: @crashmstr `When you post code here, tabs don't work well` Tabs work perfectly well in SO..for me at least ;-)

Comment: Besides that, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Novocaine: Actually, no, he's right... best to convert to space indentation for SO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know it is recommended to use spaces to ensure the intended display is shown, however every bit of code I've ever pasted using tabs has displayed as I intended it to on SO. No need to change from tabs > spaces, when SO does that automagically.

Comment: @Novocaine: SO does not do that automagically.

Comment: @Novocaine  1. It says so in the help [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 2. I've fixed indentation on many questions that had a mix, and *that* was the problem.

Comment: @crashmstr yes of course a mix will cause a problem. Tabs only, or spaces only will not. As I've said, I know it's recommended, and it's good advice to convert to spaces. But the statement tabs don't work well is not true if used exclusively.

Answer (score 6):

Here you declare a function that expects three arguments:

```
void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width);
```

Here you call it with no arguments at all:

```
intMathOperations();
```

The compiler is telling you that this is incorrect. Same for `writeHeaderLine` and `writeMathLine`.

Comment: Note: he also *defines* it with a different number of parameters from the declaration.

Comment: Well, not that one but  `void writeMathLine(int a, int b, int width);` / `void writeMathLine(int width) { }`.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling these functions without params

```
void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width);
void writeHeaderLine(int width);
void writeMathLine(int a, int b, int width);
```

Comment: I was thinking that might have been the reasoning, and I'm asking for help, not to do the my project. But thanks, I appreciate the help and concern ;)